# submit a new version before the earlier version is released iphone

Tags: iphone, submit, release, app-store-connect, ipa

I have submitted my iPhone app for release few weeks back, and it get approved and waiting my approval for release. but now I have another version which I want to submit and dont want to release the old one which is approved already.

it looks like there is no option to take care of such situation on iTunes connect.

any one have any idea?

tanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On iTunes connect, select your app, and under pricing you can set the release date in the future.  Then submit a new binary, and when it's approved, set the release date to the day the new version is approved.

Comment: I have rejected the already approved app and was able to resubmit the updated app withe the same version that was proved before.